# How would i add a playlist

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, audio-player

Hello guys i'm making a music player and it has the classes artist and songs. I need to add a playlist class which would should let you be able to add the songs i have into a new playlist and contain a method that prints the song titles of all songs it contains. i'm so lost, i'm a noob a coding but have treid my best. Any help would be great my code is below and it should use classes. i have some comments for what i needed to do but i dont know how to. the song class will need to store information about the artist name, song title and time duration of the song etc...

```
class Artist:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.modules_list = []

    def print_artist_info(self):
        print("Artist name: %s" %self.name)
        print("Artists songs:" )
        i = 0
        for c in self.modules_list:
            i+=1
            print("%d %s" %(i,c.print_module_info()))

    def enrol(self, module_running):#add new song
        self.modules_list.append(module_running)

class Songs:
    def __init__(self, song_title, artist_name, duration):
        self.song_title = song_title
        self.artist_name = artist_name
        self.duration = duration

    def print_module_info(self):#print song info
        return "Title: %s, Artist Name: %s, Duration: %s"  %(self.song_title,self.artist_name, self.duration)


class Playlist:
    def __init__(self, playlist_name):
        self.playlist_name = playlist_name
        self.playlist_list = []

    def print_playlist_info(self):
        playlistname = input("Enter Playlist Name")
        return "Playlist: %s," + (song_title) + (artist_name) + (duration),(self.playlist_name)
        




#def main
def stuff():
    
    song1 = Songs("Twinkle Twinkle Little Star","John Cena","5 Minutes")
    song2 = Songs("Mary Had A Little Lamb ",20,"3 Minutes")
    song3 = Songs("Humpty Dumpty",20,"7 Minutes")

    Artist1 = Artist("Cena John")                                                      
    Artist2 = Artist("John Bob")

    Artist1.enrol(song1)
    Artist1.print_artist_info()
    print("")
    Artist2.enrol(song2)
    Artist2.print_artist_info()
    print("")
    yesorno = input("Do You Want To Add A Song To A Playlist: ")
    if yesorno == "yes":
        song1+()
    if yesorno == "no":
        print("OK")
stuff()


#add new songs to play
#run the artist info
#favourite = playlist()
#favouritwe.addsong rolist(s1)
#favouritwe.addsong rolist(s2)

#main()
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? You already have a Playlist class, so why not just use this to create your playlist?

Comment: Yeah it is but i don't know how to I've done the top two classes using a tutorial.

Comment: Perhaps check out some tutorials on using class variables e.g. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3

Comment: ok thank you for your help its very appreciated